# Run a function and Post request Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Scource Code
https://github.com/jslack2537/PHP-Calculator 
 
Im having issues running my business logic for my calculator app at the same time as saving the results into my database they work independently just not at the same time. Im not sure if I should be combining my two controllers or what here. Any advice on the best way to combine them or make the process work as is.

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Result;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ResultController extends Controller
{
    public function postResultCreate(Request $request)
    {   $result = 2;
         $post = new Result([
             'first_number' => $request->input('first'),
             'second_number' => $request->input('second'),
             'operator' => $request->input('operator'),
             'sum' => $result
         ]);
        $post->save();
        return redirect('/')->with('info', 'Answer: ' .$result);
    }
}
```

My Second controller has the basic math logic

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CalculatorController extends Controller
{
    public function calculatefunc(Request $request)
    {
        $operator = $request->input('operator');
        $first_number = $request->input('first');
        $second_number = $request->input('second');
        $result = 0;

        if ($operator == "plus")
        {
            $result = $first_number + $second_number;
        }
        elseif($operator == "minus")
        {
            $result = $first_number - $second_number;
        }
        elseif($operator == "multiply")
        {
            $result = $first_number * $second_number;
        }
        elseif($operator == "divide")
        {
            $result = $first_number / $second_number;
        }
        else{
            $result= 0;
        }
        return redirect('/')->with('info', 'Answer: ' .$result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should combine this two classes.

Try this:

```
class CalculatorController extends Controller
{
    public function calculatefunc(Request $request)
    {
        $operator = $request->input('operator');
        $first_number = $request->input('first');
        $second_number = $request->input('second');
        $result = $this->calculateByOperator($operator, $first_number, $second_number);

        return redirect('/')->with('info', 'Answer: ' . $result);
    }

    private function calculateByOperator($operator, $first_number, $second_number)
    {
        if ($operator == "plus") {
            $result = $first_number + $second_number;
        } elseif ($operator == "minus") {
            $result = $first_number - $second_number;
        } elseif ($operator == "multiply") {
            $result = $first_number * $second_number;
        } elseif ($operator == "divide") {
            $result = $first_number / $second_number;
        } else {
            $result = 0;
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function postResultCreate(Request $request)
    {
        $first_number = $request->input('first');
        $second_number = $request->input('second');
        $operator = $request->input('operator');
        $result = $this->calculateByOperator($operator, $first_number, $second_number);
        $post = new Result([
            'first_number' => $first_number,
            'second_number' => $second_number,
            'operator' => $operator,
            'result' => $result
            // it should be result not sum because it will depend on your operator. you can also use operator here
        ]);
        $post->save();
        return redirect('/')->with('info', 'Answer: ' . $result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Glad to hear that it helps you

Comment: If you have sec check my repo and see why that code and the bottom of my view wont display any results. I believe i added the index function correctly to give the view access to the data but the code isnt working to display it

Comment: Hey, I have checked your repo and fixed your issue but can't push it. I need access to your repo.

Comment: Its a public repo you should be able to branch it and do a PR

Comment: Ill add you as a collaborator though whats you GitHub account name

Comment: My Github account name is MuktiGhosh

Comment: Okay you have been added to the repo

Comment: Check. I have made a pull request.